# How does $9\choose 4,3,2$ $=8$ $7\choose 4$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Can someone please explain to me how $9\choose 4,3,2$$=8$$7\choose 4$?

From my understanding $9\choose 4,3,2$$ = $$9\choose 4$$5\choose 3$$2\choose 2$$=$$9\choose 4$$5\choose 3$$\cdot 1$

But for some reason my teacher is jumping to simply $8$$7\choose 4$. How?

Comment: Your notation $P(9;4,3,2)$ is not standard. Do you mean a multinomial coefficient, which is ususally written $\binom9{4,3,2}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I will change that

Answer (score 1):

We have $\binom9{4,3,2}=\binom94*\binom53*\binom22=126*10*1=1260$ which is **not the same** as $8*\binom74=8*35=280$.

Comment: My teacher's answer key must have a typo then. Is there a single constant times a choose function that makes this statement true?

Comment: Given that $1260/8 = 157.5$ isn't an integer, I think it's unlikely.